# RevenueCat confirming auto-renew status via API and question on re-purchasing auto-renewables after cancellation

Tags: revenuecat

I've implemented RevenueCat for a project and am testing in the sandbox but I have a couple of questions.

1. After the 5 or 6 auto-renews have been completed in the sandbox the entitlement is no longer active. When I go to purchase the item again, pressing the same purchase button in the app, the purchase will not go through. No pop up from the app store, nothing in active entitlements like there was the first time around. Is it not possible to start another Auto-Renewable Subscription once it's been canceled or is this just a sandbox limitation?
2. I need to use the rest api to confirm the active status of my subscription, i've found these fields in the response but not sure if these are the correct ones to be checking?

- subscriber.entitlemetns.full_access.expires_date
- subscriber.subscriptions[sku].expires_date
- subscriber.subscriptions[sku].unsubscribe_detected_at

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sandbox limitation, you can read more about it on google dev page: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#renewals